# Nucleation models in Mathematica

Tags: physics, modeling, reference-request

Are there any nucleation models available in Mathematica? In particular, I am looking to implement a version of the [Kolmogorov-Johnson-Mehl-Avrami model](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333507130_The_Johnson-Mehl-Avrami-Kolmogorov_model_A_brief_review) to analyze phase-transition kinetics in one dimension.

If not, do you have any suggestions on what tools to use for this model?

Comment: Do you want to just use the KJMA model for fraction transformed, or do you want to simulate the microstructural evolution?    If you want to simulate, you can use Cahn's time cone method, which is simple in 1D.  I'll cook up a simulation if that is what you are after: it will be a straightforward application.of Nearest

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are after?

Nuclei:

```
points = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 6]
nearestNuclei = Nearest[points -> All]
```

Colors to indicate which nuclei a point on a line belongs to:

```
colors = 
 AssociationThread[
  Range[Length[points]] -> RandomColor[Length[points]]]
```

Determine which nuclei a point belongs to an color it:

```
wireColor[{point_, velocity_, time_}, nearestFunc_, colors_ ] :=
 Block[{nearestNucleus = First[nearestFunc[point]]},
  Which[
   nearestNucleus["Distance"] < velocity time,
   colors[nearestNucleus["Index"]],
   True,
   Gray
   ]
  ]
```

Draw colored line segments:

```
segment[{point_, velocity_, time_}, nearestFunc_, colors_, 
  dx_] := {wireColor[{point, velocity, time}, nearestFunc, colors], 
  Line[{{point, 0} - {dx/2, 0},
    {point, 0} + {dx/2, 0}}
   ]
  }
```

Simulate:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  {Thickness[1],
   segment[{#, 1, t}, nearestNuclei, colors, .01] & /@ 
    Range[-2, 2, .05]
   },
  Axes -> True
  ],
 {t, 0, 1}
 ]
```